# Backward propagation of type error in Haskell between unrelated functions

Tags: haskell

I am making a simple program for a demo, in which a function definition compiles (and runs) successfully, but adding a later function definition creates an error in the previous function.

This is all good:

```
factors n = [ x | x <- [2..s], mod n x ==0]
      where s = floor $ sqrt(fromIntegral n)
```

but then I added something with a mistake:

```
-- this is wrong - but why cause earlier errors?
-- getDigs ns = map digitToInt $ map show ns   -- Bad
-- getDigs ns = map digitToInt $     show ns   -- Good
getDigs :: Int -> [Int]
getDigs ns = map digitToInt $ map show ns
```

It causes an error in the previous definition, which had compiled correctly before.The error I get is:

```
preTest.hs:8:17:
    Could not deduce (RealFrac s0) arising from a use of `floor'
    from the context (Integral t)
      bound by the inferred type of factors :: Integral t => t -> [t]
      at preTest.hs:(7,1)-(8,44)
    The type variable `s0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => RealFrac (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
    In the expression: floor
    In the expression: floor $ sqrt (fromIntegral n)
    In an equation for `s': s = floor $ sqrt (fromIntegral n)
```

If I explicitly type the first function (*factors :: Int -> [Int]*) then the compiler properly finds the error where it really is, in the second function. The inferred type is:

```
factors :: Integral t => t -> [t]
```

I don't see anything shared between the two definitions, so why this interaction?

(GHCi 7.8.3)

Comment: What is the type of `factors`?

Comment: Always add explicit top level type declarations. I know many disagree, but this is a classic case where being not explicit comes and bites you in the ass.

Comment: @Jefffrey: That's a good practice, but it doesn't help in this case as far as I can tell. At least, adding `factors :: Integral t => t -> [t]` doesn't improve the error messages.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Adding `factors :: Int -> [Int]` does, which is what he seems to want. Otherwise, yes, it doesn't help, as he has to specify the type when he uses the functions, like `(factors n) :: [Int]`.

Comment: Wow, this is really weird. It's worth adding that `getDigs` and `factors` do not depend on each other, but having both changes the error messages. If you only have `factors`, everything compiles fine; if you only have `getDigs`, you only get the relevant readable error messages. But with both, you also get errors about `factors`.

Comment: Yes; The issue is not about the virtues of explicit typing, and as noted it does solve this - the question is about the unanticipated interaction of the two functions.

Comment: I've come across things like this before.  My hypothesis is that a type error causes the type checker to give up at some point before it resolves the class constraints in `factors`.  When it comes to printing the errors it sees an unresolved class constraint and complains about it.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message about `factors` with GHC 7.10.

Comment: @TomEllis: Specifically it is during the defaulting process around class constraints. Normally `factors` would be ill-formed by Prelude numeric types can be defaulted, allowing Haskell to fill in the missing type information.

Comment: Always, always, always include the GHC version number! GHC 7.8 has known problems with certain classes of type error messages; these problems were largely solved in 7.10.

Comment: [GHC 7.6 doesn't produce such errors either](http://ideone.com/2SWIdH)

Comment: Thanks, I ride along on the Haskell-Platform versions, and thus am at GHC/i 7.8.3 - which it sounds like it has known problems in this area.